# Showing that the preimage of a continuous function on R is a σ-algebra

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a continuous function on $\mathbb{R}$. Define

$\mathcal{A}=\left \{ E\subseteq \mathbb{R} : f^{-1}(E)\in \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R})\right \}$.

I want to show that $\mathcal{A}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

I think I'm just being silly, but this exercise almost seems trivial to me. I mean since $f$ is continuous, then for every open $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we know that $f^{-1}(E)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$. Then wouldn't $\emptyset, E^c \in \mathcal{A}$ if $E\in \mathcal{A}$, and that $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable unions automatically follow? What am I missing here?

Comment: Just a small observation: if f is continuous, then for every **open** $E\subseteq \mathbb{R}$ we know that $f^{-1}(E)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz Yes, I stated that above. That's why the exercise seems trivial to me. Am I right?

Comment: You should prove that it's trivial if it is :P

Comment: @MartinaK. I'm sorry, I fail to see the openness condition stated anywhere, where is it? Because not every set in the Borel algebra is open.

Comment: @EnjoysMath Well I can basically prove this in one line, right? I just want to make sure I'm not making a mistake by overlooking a detail.

Comment: @AldoGuzmánSáenz ok ok, I meant to write open, I don't know why I didn't write it before.

Comment: Hint: since the preimage of every open set is open, as well with closed sets, look at the complements of each such sets and see what you can figure out.

Answer (score 2):

Let $f$ be any map, *not necessarily continuous*.

Let $B \in \mathcal{A}$, then $f^{-1}(\mathbb{R} - B) = f^{-1}(\mathbb{R}) - f^{-1}(B) = \mathbb{R} - f^{-1}(B)$, so $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under complement.  Notice that it also contains $\mathbb{R}$, and so $\emptyset$ as well.

If $\{A_i\}_{i\geq 1} \subset \mathcal{A}$ is a countable sequence of sets, then $f^{-1}(A_1 \cup \dots) = f^{-1}(A_1) \cup \dots \ $  So $\mathcal{A}$ is closed under countable union as well.  Thus it is a $\sigma$-algebra.

You want to know if it's obvious though.  I'm not sure about that.